# Widget error with TinyMCE in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, tinymce

I'm getting this error with TinyMCE in django:

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

I have followed the instructions as I found them, and don't know why the error is there. Here is the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    """Represents a wiki article"""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))#      (help_text="Formatted using ReST")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Publish?")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedArticlesManager()
```

The comment "#formatted in ReST" is because the original TextField was using restructuredText. I was able to actually get tinyMCE from CDN and place a very simpel script in the head of the appropriate template. It loaded the wysiwyg editor, but then rendered the saved page with HTML tags visible.

So I added to form declaration as:

```
from django import forms

from models import Article, Edit, FileUploadHandler

from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        text = forms.Charfield(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))#(help_text="Formatted using ReST")
        model = Article
        exclude = ['author', 'slug']


class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Edit
        fields = ['summary']

class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUploadHandler
        image = forms.ImageField()
        fields = ['title']
```

The editor is there, but upon save its rendering the article with html tags visible. Why is that?

Comment: I believe it is a `CharField` property. http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#using-the-widget

Comment: I made some edits to the above based on the answer and comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`widget` is an attribute for form fields, not model fields. You need to move that setting to your form declaration (or `formfield_overrides` if you're trying to use it in the admin).

To display the marked up content without escaping the HTML tags in a later view, one way is to use the `|safe` built in filter.

Comment: I changed that, as you recommended but I'm still getting the html tags visible.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "upon save its rendering the article with html tags visible"? Content entered with `MCE` is supposed to be saved with HTML tags included, that's the whole point.

Comment: Yes. My understanding is that its saved to the database with html information, but I want it to be viewable on the site with the result of the formatting. So for example I wrote "<h1>FooBar</h1>." When I hit save, it returns to the article view and it shows exactly that, rather than FooBar as a heading. I know the point is to save the HTML but what about when its viewed? Is it because its in a textarea?

Comment: That depends entirely on your article view, which has nothing to do with TinyMCE. Most likely you need to use the `|safe` built in filter to deactivate HTML escaping.

Comment: Its always something simple. I added the |safe filter and we are good. Thanks for pointing a noob in the right direction.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, you may wish to accept the answer as described here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers